# Android Studio import Eclipse project from command line

Tags: android-studio, unity-game-engine, import

It possible automate import Eclipse Android Project (generated by Unity 5.4.3) into Android project with command line using android sdk?

For some reasons (eg methods limit and others) i need build android project with gradle. But Unity 5.4.3 not supported build with gradle and i can't update it for new version because i have some problems with convert my unity project to the new 5.5-5.6 versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Android Studio official document](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html), there seems no way to import an Eclipse Android Project into Android Studio using command line (bat or sh). I know that Unity 5.5 and 5.6 are not quite stable yet, but it's still your best bet to upgrade.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm currently working on a project which still uses Unity 4.7. When I try to build to Android Studio, it's quite painful. It doesn't look like the process can be automated.